# Finding multiple instances of value using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to find specific values in a worksheet and pull other info from there. However, sometimes that value occurs multiple times. In those cases I want to sum another set of values that'll be found in the same row as the found value. The code below works well to identify a specific instance of a value and then pull info ( that is the "do stuff" portion), but how would I go about looping it to pull all instances of the value and store their addresses temporarily?

Thanks!

```
Dim AccountsListLength As Integer
Dim AccountsLength As Integer
Dim CurrentAccount As String
Dim SearchISIN As String
Dim CurrentAccountPage As Range
Dim FoundISIN As Range
Dim i As Integer

SearchISIN = Worksheets("Search").Range("SearchISIN").Value
AccountsListLength = (Worksheets("DataSheet").Range("AccountList").Count)
AccountsLength = AccountsListLength - 1
For i = 0 To AccountsLength - 1

    CurrentAccount = Worksheets("DataSheet").Range("AccountList")(i + 2)
    Set CurrentAccountPage = Worksheets(CurrentAccount).UsedRange
    Set FoundISIN = CurrentAccountPage.Find(what:=SearchISIN, LookIn:=xlValues, _                 
        LookAt:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False)


    If Not FoundISIN Is Nothing Then

        'Do stuff

    End If
```

Comment: SUMIFS() will not work?

Comment: How so? I'm very new to VBA, so please pardon my ignorance.

Comment: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUMIFS-function-c9e748f5-7ea7-455d-9406-611cebce642b

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could also use FindNext.

You need to have one more var to make sure your findNext-method doesnt start all over when it reaches the last occurence

```
Dim nextISIN As Range


For i = 0 To AccountsLength - 1

CurrentAccount = Worksheets("DataSheet").Range("AccountList")(i + 2)
Set CurrentAccountPage = Worksheets(CurrentAccount).UsedRange
Set FoundISIN = CurrentAccountPage.Find(what:=SearchISIN, LookIn:=xlValues, _                 
    LookAt:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False)

Set nextISIN = CurrentAccountPage.FindNext(FoundISIN)

If Not FoundISIN Is Nothing Then

    Do Until FoundISIN == nextISIN

        'Do stuff

         Set nextISIN = CurrentAccountPage.FindNext(nextISIN)

    Loop

End If
```

This should work. However, Im writing from my cellphone while riding the train so there might be some syntax-error.

I hope it helps :)

> **Edit**: just wanted to post my comment here for a more clear view on the code

If you have a range already then you could loop through it and see if your `SearchISIN` appears more than once. If it doesn't, then `do stuff` to it.

```
Dim tempCell As Range
Dim Occurrences As Int

For Each tempCell In givenRange
    If tempCell.Value == SearchISIN Then
        Occurrences = Occurrences + 1
    End If
Next tempCell

If Occurrences == 1 Then
    'Find the cell and do stuff to it
End If
```

I'm not 100% sure on what you want to do though. Try posting some data structure next time and it will be easier for people to help :)

Comment: Thanks that does help! How would I modify this to go through all unique values in a given range, rather than a specified value (i.e., for each unique SearchISIN in a range)?

Comment: If you have a range already then you could loop through it and see if your `SearchISIN` appears more than once. If it doesn't, then `do stuff` to it.

    Dim tempCell As Range
    Dim Occurrences As Int
    
    For Each tempCell In givenRange
        If tempCell.Value == SearchISIN Then
            Occurrences = Occurrences + 1
        End If
    Next tempCell

    If Occurrences == 1 Then
        'Find the cell and do stuff to it
    End If

I'm not 100% sure on what you want to do though. Try posting some data structure next time and it will be easier for people to help :)

Comment: Thanks! That makes a lot of sense to me. I'll try it out!

Comment: I spoke too soon haha. What I'm trying to do is have it identify all unique values in a column, and then for each of those values, loop through the range and "do stuff" to it. I tried isolating them using the AdvancedFilter functionality, but that's dependent on headers which I can't have.